# Convert out of bound date in Pandas

Tags: date, replace

I have a column of dates in a CSV table. However some dates have typos such as 3021-06-30,when the real date should be 2021-06-30. How can I replace the 3021-01-01 to 2021-01-01?
I tried this but it doesn't work:
df["ddate"] = df["ddate"].replace('3021-06-30', '2021-06-30', regex=True)

I still have this error code:
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3021-06-30 00:00:00

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Datetime objects have a replace function, so you could do `df.ddate.replace(year=2021)`

Something like this could work:

```
df['ddate'] = df[
    df.ddate > dt.datetime(year=3000,month=1,day=1)
].ddate.apply(lambda x:x.replace(year=x.year - 1000)
```

This should take the year from the datetime and subtract 1000 if its past the year 3000. If the user put in 4021 though, this would not fix it.

Comment: You could do x.year - (x.year - 2000) to catch the 4k and above i suppose, but keep in mind that not all bad user inputs can be corrected. There will almost always be some margin for error that you have do drop.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! I am grateful.